# Has anyone encountered problems with Trash drives on NTFS partitions?

Tags: ntfs, trash

I have my SSD on EXT4 and my shared data drive on NTFS. Unless anyone can think of good reason not to, I want to move the Trash folder out of the cramped SSD onto the NTFS partition.

Any horror stories or problems?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you *will* run into problems, since NTFS does not support Unix permissions. Try out deleting and restoring a few files before you move your trash there for good.

That said, I found that a regular backup is a much more safe solution than Trash, and you can back up on the NTFS partition just fine.